# Changing svg path by using css

Tags: css, svg, path

How can I change a svg path with animation by using css (and javascript if I have to)? I tried to use transition and @keyframes but they didn't work. What are the ways to do this?

```css
        svg {
            overflow: initial;
            width:500px;
            height: 500px;
        }

        path {
            transition: d 0.5s;
        }

        .pa {
            
            stroke-width: 1;
            stroke:black;
            fill:transparent;
            
        }

        .a:hover .pa {
            d: path("M0 100 L240 100");
        }
```

```html
    <div class="a">
        <svg width="500" height="500">
            <path class="pa"  d="M0 100 L50 100 A 40 40 0, 0 1, 190 100 L 240 100"></path>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The number of points specified with the `d` attribute does not match with those in the css.

Check the below sample.

```css
svg {
  overflow: initial;
}
path {
  transition: d 0.5s;
}

.pa {

  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke:black;
  fill:transparent;

}
.a:hover .pa {
  d: path("M11 208H159.846C159.846 208 155.923 208 299.886 208C433.996 208 449.343 208 449.343 208H577");
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  
  <svg width="592" height="231" viewBox="0 0 592 231" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path class="pa" d="M11 208H159.846C159.846 208 155.923 71 299.886 71C433.996 71 449.343 208 449.343 208H577" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
  
</div>
```

I made the svg as below using Figma.
First created this shape.
[image]

Then draged down the central point to make the straight line as below. So the number of points in both shapes will be same.
[image]